# Homotopy Groups for Categories

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

With [this observation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64365/natural-transformations-as-categorical-homotopies) in mind how far are we from defining $\forall \mathcal{C} \  \text{category}\  \pi_1(\mathcal{C})$?
Let me be more clear.

Let be $n$ the following category $0 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 2  \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow n-1$. We might define a path in $\mathcal{C}$ any functor $\alpha \colon n\ \to \mathcal{C}$
Given two paths $\alpha: n \to \mathcal{C}, \beta: m \to \mathcal{C}$   we might define the joint path $\alpha \star \gamma: n+m \to \mathcal{C}$ in the obvious way.

We cannot (i do believe) expect to have an inverse for a path.
Now we have a notion of homotopy wich is given by natural transformation (maybe better natural equivalence?). And we can define.

$\mathcal{L}_c(\mathcal{C}):=\{\text{path who begins and end in  }c \in Ob(\mathcal C) \}$

And then $\pi_1({\mathcal{C},c}):=\mathcal{L}_c$/homotopy equivalence.

I do believe this work have been done but I haven't found anything on catlab or wikipedia.

Comment: All the homotopy groups of an essentially small category can be defined and this is well-known. You take the homotopy of the associated nerve. This is one way for instance to define the algebraic K-theory of a ring: one takes the homotopy groups of the nerve of the Q-construction applied to the category of fg projection modules over the ring.

Comment: @Jason Polak To be fair-- these constructions are not equivalent to what Ivan is suggesting.

Comment: Your composition seems ill defined whenever the two paths are not contiguous... not to mention that you have no way to identify modulo homotopy two paths having different domains

Comment: @tetrapharmakon, what you observe is bypassed using this kind of homotopy:


Given $\gamma: [0,p] \to X, \delta : [0,q] \to X (p \leq q)$  paths, we say they are homotopic if exists $F(t,s): [0, max\{p,q \}] \times [0,r] \to X$ beetween paths:
 
  \begin{matrix}
  (\gamma_{[0,t_0]} \cdot c \cdot \gamma_{[p-q,p]})& and & \delta
  \end{matrix}

Meaning $c(t) \equiv \gamma(t_0)$ for time $q-p$.

Comment: Are you aware that what you wrote has no meaning, aren't you? Is $r$ fixed, does it depend on the data of the problem? And what about $t_0$? Different choices for $r,t_0$ give the same result? Is your definition an equivalence relation of paths?

Comment: I wouldn't dare to call this constuction $\pi_1$ of a category, mainly because this is structure distinguish an n-tuple of composable arrows in the category and their composite....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment I wouldn't call this construction the $\pi_1(\mathcal C,c)$.

First of all your construction distingushes between an $n$-tuple of composable arrows in $\mathcal C$ and their composite that in topological case is not considered: this problem arise because you consider $n$-tuples of composable arrows, i.e. a functor from $n$ in $\mathcal C$, quotiented up to natural equivalence, and we known that natural transformations are defined only between parallel functors, i.e. between functors with the same source and target.

No let's see more clearly what should be an equivalence class in the set you are considering. Given two *paths* $\alpha,\beta \colon n \to \mathcal C$ a natural equivalence $\gamma \colon \alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ between them should be given
by a family of isomorphisms $\gamma_n \colon \alpha(n) \to \beta(n)$ such that obvious square commutes. That implies that for every $i=1,\dots,n-1$ the arrows 
$\alpha(i-1) \to \alpha(i)$ and $\beta(i-1) \to \beta(i)$ should be isomorphic in the arrow category. So an equivalence class in this case could be more likely be called a factorization class for a path, instead of a path, since such equivalence class retain up to isomorphism the factorization of an arrow.

It seems that what are you willing to do is to treat a category as a [directed space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_algebraic_topology#Directed_Spaces) and calculate the fundamental group of this space. I don't get the utility of this construction since the only way I see to  continue on this road is a construction that would give you the group of automorphisms of an object quotiented up to isomorphism.

What can be a useful construction instead is to consider the nerve of the category $\mathcal C$ and the study its fundamental group (which is really similar to what is done for the study of the homology of groups).

Comment: In fact, $\pi_n(C)$ is defined to be $\pi_n(N(C))$, where $N(-)$ is the nerve construction.